# Which classification metric to use and why?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes

I have a random forest classification model that classifies into 3 different labels. The thing is my data is unbalanced label 1 dominates the data with frequency of 0.5 while label 2 is around 0.35 and the third one is 0.15.

Which classification metric would you recommend me to use in order to evaluate my candidate models. what is your rational ?

thank you all in advance !